# Scrapy output empty

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to extract paper titles from IEEE Xplore by

`scrapy shell 'https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=5962385'`

For the first paper title, I used copy Xpath to get the Xpath. Then, I tried

`response.xpath('//*[@id="publicationIssueMainContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/xpl-issue-results-list/div[2]/div[4]/div/xpl-issue-results-items/div[2]/div[2]/h2/a').getall()`.

I also tried `response.css(div.List-results-items)`

However, there is no output for both of these two methods.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Data is dynamically loaded via xhr POST request. You could simply use requests to issue xhr to get all pages results as json

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Referer': 'https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=5962385',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'cache-http-response': 'false',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('punumber', '5962385'),
)

data = {"punumber":"5962385","sortType":"vol-only-seq","isnumber":8809853}
results = {}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post('https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/rest/search/pub/5962385/issue/8809853/toc', headers=headers, params=params, json=data).json()
    results[1] = r
    num_pages = r['totalPages']

    for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
        data['pageNumber'] = page
        r = s.post('https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/rest/search/pub/5962385/issue/8809853/toc', headers=headers, params=params, json=data).json()
        results[page] = r
```